# Parse CSV to JavaScript and use a kind of VLOOKUP

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a selection box which simply sends value to the function. Function then gets a number 1-100. I have a CSV file with 100 rows and 5 columns. I want to create a function which will parse values from columns 4-5 based on the row number that it was previously sent by the selection box to 4 different variables inside that function. Can you please let me know what needs to be used to achieve that?

Lets say CSV looks like

```
1, Robert, Lee, robert@mymail.com, 100001
2, John, Smith, john@mymail.com, 10002
3, Scott, Jones, scott@mymail.com, 10003
4, etc.
```

So when I select 1 from dropmenu.
I should get "Robert", "Lee", "robert@mymail.com", "100001" assigned to variables like

```
var firstname = 
var lastname =
var email =
var idn =
```

UPDATE after first comment:

Let's make this simpler.

Let's say I have HTML

```
<button id="1" onclick="getcolumns(this)">One</button>
<button id="2" onclick="getcolumns(this)">Two</button>
<button id="3" onclick="getcolumns(this)">Three</button>
<button id="4" onclick="getcolumns(this)">Four</button>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Then JS function

```
function getcolumns(button) {
    var idm = buttton.id;
    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = idm;
}
```

So let's say I press button 'Three' then innerHTML displays '3'.

I need function which will be based on diagram below:

```
function getcolumns(button) {
    [GET File.csv]
    var idm = buttton.id; // lets say idm = 3 at the moment//
    [Parse values from Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, from ROW(idm)]
    var firstname = col2;
    var lastname = col3;
    var email = col4;
    var idn = col5;
    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = col2+'<br>'+col3+'<br>'+col4+'<br>'+col5
}
```

So basically I will get

```
<div id="area">
 Scott
 Jones
 scott@mymail.com
 10003
</div>
```

Comment: Hope its clearer now :)

Comment: what does your JavaScript look like right now?

Comment: Done it there, hope you can help me now. I have been searching in the meantime, apparently it's not that easy to parse a CSV file into JS function. Once I will find a possibility I will need to put this into array and then read it from there.

Comment: I use the JQuery-CSV plugin, and it's pretty simple. I'll share the code I use.

Comment: Will that parse the CSV directly to the array? So then when I press the button this will call variables from it?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [JQuery-CSV plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) (warning: This plugin has a bug with Mac CSV files. I have it fixed in my fork of it, just need to upload it to github).

#### HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="handleFileSelect()" />
```

To deal with the file:

JavaScript function to reset the input in case a bad file is chosen (necessary for onchange to work)

```
var resetInput = function(inputSelector) {
    $(inputSelector).wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
    $(inputSelector).unwrap();
}
```

JavaScript function to parse CSV into columns

```
var updateDom = function(file, onError) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var data;
            try {
                data = $.csv.toObjects(csv);
                fileUploaded = true;
            }
            catch(e) {
                importErrorMessage = "Your CSV File could not be imported. The error has been logged. If it's an error we can fix, we will.";
                onError();
                fileUploaded = false;
                console.log(e);
                return;
            }
            csv = {dataRows : data};
            var columns = [];//header row
            for (var prop in data[0])
            {
                columns.push(prop);
            }
            //update dom here
        }
    };
var importErrorMessage = "";
```

Actually handles the logic to ensure a correct type of file is chosen.

```
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    if(evt &&evt.files[0]) {
        var file = evt.files[0];
            if(file.name.split('.').pop() != 'csv' && (
                file.type !== 'text/csv' ||
                file.type !== 'text/comma-separated-values' ||
                file.type !== 'application/csv' ||
                file.type !== 'application/excel' ||
                file.type !== 'application/vnd.ms-excel' ||
                file.type !== 'text/anytext')) {
                    console.log(file.type);
                    importErrorMessage = "Incorrect file type uploaded. We only accept files ending in .csv";
                    resetInput(evt);
                    return;
            }
            var callback = function() {
                resetInput(evt);
                fileUploaded = false;

            }
                updateDom(file, callback);
        }

    };
```

Comment: Thanking you :) although I dont need the script which requires CSV upload but a script which loads the CSV automatically from a URL. Would something like that work? 'var file = http.open("GET", "test.csv");' I also don't need the error check as I know the CSV will always be constant.

Comment: @Matt You're more confident than I am about CSV files.  This doesn't upload the CSV file to the server (indeed, upload is a misnomer) as it just loads the CSV file into memory. To read a file from a remote URL, you just need to change the part of the code that reads in the file to take it from a remote URL. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64ea2d16-7594-400b-8b25-8b3b9a078eab/read-external-text-file-with-javascript?forum=sidebargadfetdevelopment